# Lego EV3 Brick turn right by tkinter command

Tags: python, tkinter, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Hi I want to control my lego EV3 brick through a command from my computer to turn right by pressing on a GUI button on Tkinter through python, I have no clue how to do so as I cannot interrupt the vs code program. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a bit of code? Like what you have to call to make your lego EV3 brick to turn? I don't think there are a lot of people who know how to use both lego EV3 bricks and tkinter.

Comment: Refer the [official document](https://education.lego.com/en-us/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/teacher-resources/python-for-ev3).

Comment: Do you want to communicate with your robot using wireless (like Bluetooth or XBee), or using a wired connection (like a USB serial port)? The latter would be easier and more reliable, but it all depends on what your needs are.